# DevOps Roadmap: Underststanding OS Concepts

Tags: learning

According to the [DevOps Roadmap](https://roadmap.sh/devops) from roadmap.sh, understanding the following OS topics are recommended:

- Process Management
- Threads and Concurrency
- Sockets
- POSIX Basics
- Networking Concepts
- I/O Management
- Virtualization
- Memory/Storage
- File Systems

Are there recommended materials on these topics? It would be good to compile resources and classes (perhaps from coursera, udemy, EdX etc.)

Comment: A number of courses exist on YouTube and some are from reputable universities. I am following [one from Berkley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hry_qqXLej8&list=PLRdybCcWDFzCag9A0h1m9QYaujD0xefgM&index=1)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't taken this course, but perhaps this EdX course [Computer Hardware and Operating Systems](https://www.edx.org/course/computer-hardware-and-operating-systems?index=product&queryID=9edb358f06086b32783a54f997c00313&position=1) from NYU might be a good starting place.

Current outline is:

- Week 1 - Fundamentals of system hardware
- Week 2 - Introduction to OS concepts
- Week 3 - Processes & threads
- Week 4 - Thread concurrency and deadlocks
- Week 5 - Memory management
- Week 6 - Exam

Has explicit coursework for a number of the topics posed in my original question (3 by my count).

Comment: Could you pull some of the information from that link into this answer please, to protect against bitrot? The link is not guaranteed to exist in the future. What is the course called? what is the outline, why did you suggest it?

Comment: Posted some info